# Tensorflow.js Dataset to Tensor?

Tags: tensorflow.js

Is there a recommended/efficient way to convert a `tf.data.Dataset` to a `Tensor` when the underlying 'data examples' in the `Dataset` are flat arrays?

I am using `tf.data.csv` to read and parse a CSV but then want to use the Tensorflow.js Core API to process the data as `tf.Tensors`.

Comment: The elements of the stream produced by `tf.data.csv()` are dicts with primitive values, i.e. numbers and strings.  Those will be automatically converted to Tensors when you pass them to core API functions, so you don't need to worry about that.  One special case is if you call `batch()` on your stream, in which case the resulting batches are already Tensors.

Answer (score 1):

Beware that this workflow is not typically recommended, because materializing
all the data in the main JavaScript memory may not work for large CSV datasets.

You can use the `toArray()` method of `tf.data.Dataset` objects. For example:

```
  const csvUrl =
'https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-examples/multivariate-linear-regression/data/boston-housing-train.csv';

  const csvDataset = tf.data.csv(
     csvUrl, {
       columnConfigs: {
         medv: {
           isLabel: true
         }
       }
     }).batch(4);

  const tensors = await csvDataset.toArray();
  console.log(tensors.length);
  console.log(tensors[0][0]);
```

Comment: I *think* the OP's question was about getting data for each example in Tensor form, rather than materializing the whole Dataset into a single Tensor.  This answer applies to the latter case (which is indeed not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

`tf.data.Dataset.iterator()` returns a promise of an iterator.

```js
const it = await flattenedDataset.iterator()
   const t = []
   // read only the data for the first 5 rows
   // all the data need not to be read once 
   // since it will consume a lot of memory
   for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let e = await it.next()
      t.push(...e.value)
   }
  tf.concat(await t, 0)
```

Using [for await of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

```
const asyncIterable = {
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    return {
      i: 0,
      async next() {
        if (this.i < 5) {
          this.i++
          const e = await it.next()
          return Promise.resolve({ value: e.value, done: false });
        }

        return Promise.resolve({ done: true });
      }
    };
  }
};

  const t = []
  for await (let e of asyncIterable) {
        if(e) {
          t.push(e)
        }
   }
```

```js
const csvUrl =
'https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-examples/multivariate-linear-regression/data/boston-housing-train.csv';

(async function run() {
   // We want to predict the column "medv", which represents a median value of
   // a home (in $1000s), so we mark it as a label.
   const csvDataset = tf.data.csv(
     csvUrl, {
       columnConfigs: {
         medv: {
           isLabel: true
         }
       }
     });

   // Number of features is the number of column names minus one for the label
   // column.
   const numOfFeatures = (await csvDataset.columnNames()).length - 1;

   // Prepare the Dataset for training.
   const flattenedDataset =
     csvDataset
     .map(([rawFeatures, rawLabel]) =>
       // Convert rows from object form (keyed by column name) to array form.
       [...Object.values(rawFeatures), ...Object.values(rawLabel)])
      .batch(1)
  
 const it = await flattenedDataset.iterator()
  const asyncIterable = {
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    return {
      i: 0,
      async next() {
        if (this.i < 5) {
          this.i++
          const e = await it.next()
          return Promise.resolve({ value: e.value, done: false });
        }

        return Promise.resolve({ done: true });
      }
    };
  }
};
  
  const t = []
  for await (let e of asyncIterable) {
     if(e) {
          t.push(e)
        }
   }
  console.log(tf.concat(t, 0).shape)
})()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.1"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```